# Generate a random Number in a table column based on other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new in `SQL`. can anybody help me to resolve my query.

I want to generate a Number in GenerateproductNumber column like

> PDT-1201/1-P1,PDT-1201/1-P2 based on ProductNumber column.

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Kindly share expected result on the basis of your sample data

Comment: please provide more info ? any code sample that you have tired ?

Comment: **PDT-1201/1-P1, PDT-1201/1-P2**
Please explain this.

Comment: 'PDT-1201/1-P' is a prefix which is static in other table,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, you're looking :

```
SELECT *,
       'PDT-1201/1-P'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductNumber ORDER BY ID)) [GenerateproductNumber]
FROM <table_name>;
```

**Result :**

```
ID  CustomerID  Supplier    Product ProductNumber   GenerateproductNumber
1   2           ABC PVT LTD Jeans   1               PDT-1201/1-P1
2   3           Pk PVT LTD  Jeans   1               PDT-1201/1-P2
```

Comment: Yeah. I want to generate like that

Answer (score 0):

you may use update command (if not null constraint not applied on GenerateproductNumber)
First insert record in your table, then update GenerateproductNumber column

```
UPDATE your_table_name SET GenerateproductNumber = 'PDT-1201/1-P'||char(ProductNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

if data/value of GeneratedProductNumber column is depend upon other column value/data or upon calculation then you can use **Computed Column** concept in sql server.

Please refer below link for more information:-

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/computed-columns-in-sql-server/